# Protected Range leads to "Can't sync your changes. Copy your recent edits, then revert your changes." Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm getting this error when I use protected range, whether I do it through app script or using Google Sheet "Protect Range" Menu.

My intention is to protect row number 1,2,3 from each tab on a sheet, it does work as intended and prevent people from editing the Rows 1,2,3 but it also prevents people from moving the Rows below. Im just trying to protect the headers and I cannot make sense of why this error is happening.

Here is the App Script Code:

```
function createProtectedRange() {

// Protect range A1:AN3, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var range = ss.getRange('A1:AN3');
var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Protected range');
// Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
// permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon removing the group.
var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
protection.addEditor(me);
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}

}
```

The result is the same if I use the Google Sheet Menu

[Protect Range Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trx5G.png)

Any Ideas? All I need is to prevent individuals from changing the first top 3 rows.
But still, give them the ability to move rows below.
Keep in mind that there are quite a few formulas (Array Formulas) on the first 3 Rows.

Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error using your script.  I would however advise `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` returns a spreadsheet, change to `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSpreadsheet();`  or `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");` as appropriate.

Comment: @TheWizEd I'm getting this error when using:    

    `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSpreadsheet();`

`TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getActive(...).getActiveSpreadsheet is not a function`

The idea is to lock all first 3 Rows, without affecting other Editors to move all the rows below up and down. Which is not the case right now.

Comment: I'm sorry, had a temporary brain fog.  `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` returns a spreadsheet.  It should be `var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();` which returns a sheet.